# RoR Migrate from cloudinary to carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cloudinary

Since we're not going to use `cloudinary` anymore, how can I migrate all our cloud images to `carrierwave`?

There is a [tutorial](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_additional_topics#migration) for migration *to* cloudinary, but not backward.
Can anyone help, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I ended up with something like this:

1) Generated an image uploader

```
# encoding: utf-8
class GiftImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

2) Created rake-task `lib/tasks/pictures.rake`

```
namespace :pictures do
  desc 'Download images of gifts from Cloudinary to the localhost'
  task :download => :environment do

    Picture.all.each do |pic|
      if pic.image.to_s.include? 'cloudinary'
        uploader = GiftImageUploader.new(pic)
        uri = pic.image.to_s
        url = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/<domain_name>/image/upload/' + pic.image.filename
        puts url
        begin
          uploader.download! url
          uploader.store!
          puts pic.id.to_s + '  ' + (pic.title != nil ? pic.title : '') + '    100% download'
          pic.gift_image = uploader
          pic.save
          puts 'SAVED'
        rescue
          puts 'Error with ' + pic.id.to_s + '  ' + (pic.title != nil ? pic.title : '') + '!'
        end
      end
    end
    puts 'Done all!'
  end
end
```

And it was successful for me.